# Does my app service share VM/outgoing IP with other people's app service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Since App Service is multi-tenant infrastructure, is it true that my app service might share same underlying VM and outgoing IP with other app service which not owned by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your app service will share the same outgoing IP. App services in the same plan will share a load balancer, and will use one of four IP's for outgoing traffic.

The IP's are shown in the Azure portal in the app service's properties, and can also be retrieved using powershell.

Details about the network traffic for app services: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-network-architecture-overview